# Javascript: displaying tooltip when mouse is hovered a certain word in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, tooltip

So I have a textarea containing text.  I want to be able to display a tooltip when my mouse is hovered a certain word inside the textarea.

Is this possible at all?  I would prefer to see a solution that doesn't use any third party javascript libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to use a "richtext" field (eg `contentEditable` and `designMode`), you can wrap the word with a `<span>` and attach `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to it. The big drawback with this approach is that "richtext" features that you may not want can be invoked with keyboard shortcuts in some browsers even if you don't provide an interface for them, and you'll need to filter those styles either while editing or after saving to a `<textarea>`.

Alternatively, you can have a hidden (but not `display: none`, as this will prevent accurate measurement) `<div>`* and update its content as the `<textarea>` changes, wrap the word with a `<span>` as in the option above, and display the tooltip if the cursor position's offset relative to the `<textarea>` is within bounds that would be over the `<span>` relative the hidden `<div>`. To determine position you'd probably want to start a `mousemove` event observer if there is a `mouseover` event on the `<textarea>`, and stop the `mousemove` event if there is a `mouseout` event on the `<textarea>`.

* Note: In order to ensure correct positioning, this `<div>` should have exactly the same font, text, line and dimensional styles as the textarea, and when mirroring the content you'll need to escape HTML special characters (`&`, `<` and `>`), as well as convert new lines to `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a contentEditable rich text editor, you would probably have to create some code that mimics the layout of a textarea and associates a word with a mouse range to determine hover over a certain text, or you could do it on the selection of a bit of text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this for a particular word in , you can either have it for the whole textarea